# How can we decide to use UICollectionViewController or UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

If we want to have `UICollectionView` in current page, how can we decide whether to use `UICollectionViewController`, or `UIViewController`?

The advantages I can observe is that, using `UICollectionViewController` requires less setup.

- We need not call `self.collectionView.registerClass`
- We need not call `self.collectionView.delegate = self`
- We need not call `self.collectionView.dataSource = self`

Besides that, what else we should consider, when choosing between `UICollectionViewController` and `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` has `UIView` as base view where as `UICollectionViewController` has `UICollectionView` as base view, hence no other view can be added in `UICollectionViewController`. If you want to add multiple views along with `UICollectionView` then you have to use `UIViewController`.

[image: This is UICollectionViewController] and [image: This is UIViewController]

You can add multiple CollectionViews, TableViews, Buttons, Labels in `UIView`. So basically all developers are prefer `UIViewController` and if your screen has only a CollectionView then you can use `UICollectionViewController`.